# Bundle não funciona quando publico o site

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou utilizando o `BundleConfig.cs` no meu projeto para referenciar as bibliotecas JS e CSS. Segue abaixo exemplos:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
            "~/Content/Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/font-awesome").Include(
            "~/Content/CSS/base/font-awesome.css"));
```

Para utilizá-los, faço da seguinte forma:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/font-awesome")
```

No arquivo `BundleConfig.cs`, também tenho a instrução abaixo:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

O problema é que quando publico meu site no IIS7, a aplicação não consegue identificar os arquivos e adicionar a referência dos mesmos.

A pasta `bundle` é criada da maneira correta, conforme imagem abaixo, porém parece que o site não consegue reconhecê-los:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já fiz o teste de adicionar as configurações abaixo no `web.config`, mas sem sucesso

```
<location path="bundles">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Na vez em que isso aconteceu aqui, depois de muito esforço descobrimos que o problema ocorria porque o meu chefe mesclava a pasta Scripts na hora de fazer o deploy (ao invés de deletar e colar a versão nova). As pastas que ficavam lá de resíduo conflitavam com os nomes dos bundles.  Não parece ser o seu caso, só estou comentando aqui para os próximos que consultarem essa pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Este problema é um pouco complexo e bizarro porque a solução não é óbvia. O problema está na referência ao seu CSS.

Aqui:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/font-awesome").Include(
        "~/Content/CSS/base/font-awesome.css"));
```

Você está forçando a criação de uma rota em cima de um diretório estático, o que confunde o IIS. A presepada foi da própria equipe que escreveu o mecanismo de *Bundling*. O certo seria utilizar uma rota em cima de um diretório que não existe para funcionar corretamente. [A explicação completa está aqui](http://www.mvccentral.net/Story/Details/articles/kahanu/stylebundle-403-error-solved).

Para resolver, basta usar outro nome de rota (ou de diretório, como quiser):

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/BundledStyles/css/font-awesome").Include( // Eu uso assim
        "~/Content/CSS/base/font-awesome.css"));
```

### E por que funciona no IIS Express?

Porque ele possui menos manipuladores de rotas, incluindo a ausência do manipulador estático, que é o que causa essa confusão.

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém ainda tenha problemas com isso, depois de apanhar bastante, eu fiz meio que o contrario do que foi falado aqui no inicio deste post, e deu certo.

no meu bundle.config eu force, false no EnableOptimizations.

```
bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

No Config eu deixei da seguinte forma:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <!--<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />-->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="BundleModule" />
      <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
    </modules>
```

E deu certo.

Comment: Faltou um trecho.

Comment: No Config eu deixei da seguinte forma:
  <system.webServer>
    <!--<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />-->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="BundleModule" />
      <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
    </modules>